# Xcode NSDictionary Subdictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I have dictionary which i want to use to fill a tableview. It is parsed by JSON.

My dictionary looks like that:

```
NSLog(@"%@",temp);

// OUTPUT //

(
        {
        ShootingDate = "2013-07-29 00:00:00";
        ShootingID = 1;
        ShootingName = Testshooting;
    },
        {
        ShootingDate = "2013-06-12 00:00:00";
        ShootingID = 2;
        ShootingName = Architektur;
    }
)
```

Dictionary looks in XCode like that:

[image]

Now i want to fill a table with that data. Each row should display ShootingDate,ShootingID and ShootingName but i am not able to access these keys.

Anyone a suggestion?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not able to access these keys"? What code have you tried?

Comment: I tried this for example:
`NSDictionary *tempDicts=[temp objectForKey:@"0.ShootingName"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all temp is not dictionary it is NSArray and u can get it as

```
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in temp) {
    [dictionary valueForKey:@"ShootingDate"];
    [dictionary valueForKey:@"ShootingID"];
    [dictionary valueForKey:@"ShootingName"];
}
```

You can get your dictionary in cellforRow as

```
 NSDictionary *tempDicts=[temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"id=%@,date=%@,name=%@",[tempDicts  valueForKey:@"ShootingID"],[tempDicts  valueForKey:@"ShootingDate"],[tempDicts  valueForKey:@"ShootingName"]];
```

Comment: Your loop is working fine but this causes an error:
`NSDictionary *tempDicts=[temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`
because is an dictionary
`Error: no visible @interface`

Comment: You set temp as an `NSDictionary` object, but really it's an `NSArray`. You need to create `NSArray* temp = ...` and not `NSDictionary* temp = ...`.

Comment: yes @Liron is right you are showing temp as array in your question.

Comment: Oh yes right. Thank you it is working!
I changed temp to an NSArray

Answer (score -1):

you can access these keys as

```
    NSString *str_ShootingDate = [[temp objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] 
    objectForKey:@"ShootingDate"];  //you can change this key with ShootingID 
    //or ShootingName
```

Comment: thats not working because `objectAtIndex` is not valid for NSDictionary

Comment: your variable temp is an array so you need to use objectAtIndex for that and then objectForKey for that dictionary which is at that index.

Comment: Oh yes right. Thank you it is working!
I changed temp to an NSArray